# AngularJS pass string to function by ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to pass a string to a function through ng click, here's an example

HTML

`<a class="btn"> ng-click="test(STRING_TO_PASS)"</a>`

Controller

`$scope.test = function(stringOne, stringTwo){
    valueOne = test(STRING_TO_PASS);
}`

Edit -

Turns out I was thinking about this the wrong way... not really sure why I asked it, sorry guys!

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: What is the problem? test function is undefined in your controller, have you defined it anywhere else! you should use ng-click like this: 'test("STRING_TO_PASS")', if its not a angular variable.

Comment: in your controller it would be: `$scope.test = function(STRING_TO_PASS)`, what kind of behaviour / logic are you looking for?

Comment: Edited question. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller function should accept only 1 parameter

```
$scope.test = function(stringOne){
    valueOne =  stringOne;
}
```

Comment: i think now you should be able to

Answer (score 1):

Correct HTML for `ng-click` to be used as an attribute is as

```
<a class="btn" ng-click="test('STRING_TO_PASS')"> Click</a>
```

Also, the `test` function would accept one parameter in your controller.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
$scope.test = function(stringOne) {
    valueOne = stringOne;
    console.log(valueOne);
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <a class="btn" ng-click="test('STRING_TO_PASS')"> Click</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
HTML

<a class="btn"> ng-click="test("StringOne","StringTwo")"</a>

Controller

$scope.test = function(stringOne, stringTwo){
    var valueOne = stringOne;
var valueTwo = stringTwo
}
```